# Calling an app from the terminal via script

Tags: macos, command-line

I try to call an application from the console and pass it an argument. This is the script I am using:

```
#!/bin/sh

open -a "/Applications/MyApp.app/" $1
```

Somehow the OS is unhappy with this and complains:

```
FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/MyApp.app) failed with error -43.
```

What can I do?

Comment: That looks like /Applications/MyApp.app doesn't actually exist.  You sure it's there?

Comment: Thanks! That was silly. Sorry for asking, but at least I now know what error 43 means ...

Comment: `Mac OS error -43 (fnfErr): File not found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like /Applications/MyApp.app doesn't actually exist.

You can test for that in your script, perhaps like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
APP=/Applications/MyApp.app
if [ ! -d "$APP" ]; then
  echo >&2 "$0: $APP not found."
  exit 1
fi
exec open -a "$APP" "$@"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make sure the application exists before calling `open` on it! Here's a quick bit of Bash to do this:

```
if [ -d "/Applications/MyApp.app" ]; then
    open -a "/Applications/MyApp.app"
else
    echo "Application /Applications/MyApp.app does not exist!"
fi
```